# Coroutine in python between 3.4 and 3.5, How can I keep backwords compatibility?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm on developing python chatting bot framework with `asyncio`. But I watch [PEP-492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492) and there is new syntax, `async`/`await` and finally it accepted.

I like `async`/`await` syntax and I want to use it. but I worry about 3.4 backwords compatibility.

If I use new syntax in my code, someone can use it in 3.4?

For example, I write some code like this,

```
import asyncio

class ChatBot:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop

    async def connect(self):
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connect(HOST, PORT, loop=self.loop)

    async def read():
        return await self.reader.read()

    async def run(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            try:
                await self.connect()
                line = await self.read()
                if not line:
                    continue
                await self.parse(line)
            except BotInternalError as e:
                if e.stop:
                    running = False
                    break
            except:
                pass

    async def parse(self, msg):
        if msg.startswith('PING'):
            self.pong()
        elif msg.startswith('ERROR'):
            self.error()
        else:
            await self.some_work(msg)

    async def some_work(self, msg):
        # some looooooooong works
        self.send(msg)

    def send(self, msg):
        self.writer.write(msg)
```

Than, I can use it with this source in py35

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # I don't know it really needed in py35.
bot = ChatBot(loop)
asyncio.run_until_complete(bot.run())
```

But, py34 don't have `await` syntax. If I uploaded above source at PyPI without version constraint and someone installed it on py34, It'll work fine? How can I keep it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need to support Python 3.4 in your code, you'll need to use the old `@asyncio.coroutine`/`yield from` style syntax. There's no way to support the `async`/`await` syntax without running 3.5; you'll get a `SyntaxError` at compilation time on 3.4 or lower.

The only thing that takes advantage of the new features you *can* do in a backwards-compatible way is add the various `__a*__` methods to your classes where appropriate (`__aiter__`, `__aenter__`, `__aexit__`, etc.), using the `yield from` coroutine syntax. That way, your objects can support `async with`/`async for` statements, so that users of your library running Python 3.5 could take advantage of the new features.

For example, this class can be used with `async with`, but won't break when run on Python 3.4:

```
import asyncio

class Test:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("arg")

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def __aenter__(self):
        yield from self.init_state()
        return self

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def init_state(self):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(2) # Pretend this is real initialization

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def __aexit__(self, *args):
        return self.__exit__(self, *args)
```

On Python 3.5:

```
import asyncio
from test import Test

async def main():
    print("entering with")
    async with Test() as t:
        print("in here")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

On Python 3.4

```
import asyncio
from test import Test

@asyncio.coroutine
def oldmain():
    print("entering with")
    with Test() as t:
        yield from t.init_state()
        print("in here")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(oldmain())
```

This probably isn't useful if you're writing an application that uses `asyncio`, but if you're developing a library or framework intended to be used by other developers,  it's worth doing.

Comment: It's amusing to see the `@asyncio.coroutine` construction described as "old" when it only appeared in the most recent Python version. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Indeed. Python is evolving rather quickly in this space. :)

Comment: So because the transition between Python 2 and Python 3 was so easy, the Python community decided to also make the transition simple between Python 3.4 and Python 3.5 :-) ?

Comment: `you'll get a SyntaxError at compilation time on 3.4 or lower` - this is actually a weird problem.

We could add import guards and allow new features only for 3.5+, but now we need to have separate codebase for 3.4 and 3.5+. And wait a minute, 3.4 is standard Python on LTS Ubuntu 14.04, so it will be maintained until 2017!

I think something wrong with that :)